# How to do transmission and reception using aux cable when it configured as line-in?

Tags: audio, acer-aspire, headphone-jack

Setup I am using : on transmitted end, a laptop is connected to mobile phone using TRS aux cable in the headphone jacks of both and same in the reception side also. now, I calling from one end to send the sound like signal from transmitted end. I configured the aux cable as line-in option in my laptop to listen better the received signal from phone call on the reception side.

now, If I have have to do same process from receiving end(consider 1st end to avoid confusion) to other end also, does it work? or should I reset the configuration to headset from line in on this 1st end. again configure the 2nd end as line-in?

Can't I make it duplex i.e., avoiding configuration each time when I transmit and receive from one end to other end and in opposite also?
[image]

More or less this is the setup I am using..(there is no headset in my setup)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do duplex on a 3.5mm jack is with TRRS. You need two TRRS splitters and two TRS cables (for each laptop-phone combo). Plug the splitters into your laptop and the phone, then connect the headphone ports of the splitters to the mic ports of each other.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).